# shows blank page after deploying a grails war file on openshift

Tags: mysql, tomcat, grails, openshift, war

i deployed a war file to openshift after creating a tomcat 7(JBoss EWS 2.0) app using the following guide lines [(deploy war file using git)](https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/deployment-options.html) 
but after deploying my app it only shows a blank page. here are the logs i got by using the **rhc tail** command.

```
==> app-root/logs/jbossews.log <==
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoa
der.java:1571)
        at net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValuesView.iterator(
ConcurrentHashMap.java:3252)
        at net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.ExtendedStatisticsImpl$1.run(Exten
dedStatisticsImpl.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

==> app-root/logs/mysql.log <==
160420 10:20:46 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160420 10:20:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160420 10:20:47 InnoDB: 5.5.45 started; log sequence number 1595675
160420 10:20:47 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.9.179.2'; port: 3306

160420 10:20:47 [Note]   - '127.9.179.2' resolves to '127.9.179.2';
160420 10:20:47 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.9.179.2'.
160420 10:20:47 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@ex-std-node563.prod.rhclo
ud.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
160420 10:20:47 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160420 10:20:47 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connec
tions.
Version: '5.5.45'  socket: '/var/lib/openshift/571649900c1e669c5c00017c/mysql//s
ocket/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

==> app-root/logs/phpmyadmin.log <==
[Tue Apr 19 11:24:41 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 configured --
 resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 19 12:27:32 2016] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Tue Apr 19 12:27:32 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authent
ication ...
[Tue Apr 19 12:27:32 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Apr 19 12:27:32 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 configured --
 resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 20 10:20:38 2016] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Apr 20 10:21:05 2016] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as con
text unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c4,c884
[Wed Apr 20 10:21:05 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authent
ication ...
[Wed Apr 20 10:21:05 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Apr 20 10:21:05 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 configured --
 resuming normal operations
```

the name of the war file i deployed is **ROOT.war** using git push and it deployed successfully.i am using mysql database and phpmyadmin cartridges.
i just want to figure out why it is showing me a blank page when i try to access the url of my application.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed the problem with the help i got from @Taras Kohut. i added the following lines to my BuildConfig.groovy file.

```
 grails.project.war.exploded.dir = "/yourLocalPathToClonedOpenshiftFile/webapps/ROOT"
 grails.war.exploded=true
```

the above lines will generate an exploded war file in your openshift app in the webapps folder.
next i added **ROOT.war.deploy** file again in the webapps directory.This is a file which instructs jboss that after the push it must take the ROOT folder and deploy it on Tomcat (which is emulated by JBoss) as if it was a war file.
after that i committed and pushed my changes and the app is deployed successfully and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The log you provided is not helpfull at all, because it's not full, I even can't see what exception was thrown.

This is the best article about deploying grails application on OpenShift, it will help you a lot: 
[Grails on Openshift](http://keyboarddays.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-on-openshift.html)

Also the troubleshoutting will be more productive if you use ftp to see what's going on on your server 
[Using FileZilla and SFTP on Windows with OpenShift](https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/)

Comment: tnx very much. the first link you provided led me to a solution to my problem. i will post the full answer below.

Comment: no problem. You can vote or accept this post if it's helpful